# Docker run -v not syncing

Tags: docker, volume, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to spin a container from a docker image while using the -v option to mount a local volume. My understanding is that the container designated folder should sync up with the local directory, so that any update in any side is going to happen on the other side as well.

This is not happening though, the local files are not being copied to the container, and vice versa. Is this not how it's supposed to work?

Here is the command I use to spin the container:

```
docker run -dit --name zeppelin -p 4444:8080 -v /home/sammy/mnt/Zeppelin_Notebook:/zeppelin/notebook apache/zeppelin:0.9.0
```

Comment: Nothing is copied. The directory on your host is mounted inside the container. They are the same directory. How did you determine that it's not working?

Comment: The local direcoty (/home/sammy/mnt/Zeppelin_Notebook) has zeppelin notebook files. they are not copied to the (/zeppelin/notebook) in the container. Also any notebook files I create in the container are not copied back to the local directory.  Isn't that how volumes are supposed to work?

Comment: The files should be visible from both the host and from inside the container, yes. But as I said, nothing is copied. Show your setup and the steps you take to be able to reproduce this. Since this is the normal way of doing it, I'm not going to take your word that it "does't work" unless you can show me the steps to reproduce it. At this point I'm still assuming that there is nothing wrong with the bind mount, but probably the issue lies somewhere else. In order to get an actual answer you need to give sufficient information.

Comment: It works for me (changes in host are visible in container, I can't test the other way round because I don't know root password) but the directory remains empty, as if the application is not configured to store anything there. If I run it without the `-v` part I don't get any `/zeppelin/notebook` folder at all. So I guess the issue is in the application side.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that I messed up the container path. I needed /opt/ in front of /zeppelin/notebook. Classic silly mistakes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).